# Extract only the matched text with a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am reading in a whole txt file and attempting to find specific portions of a string.  For instance, I am looking for the string "Date: 23 Sep 2017".  Of course the date is going to change, which is not my issue. What happens is that I get the entire rest of the file once it finds my match.  My question is how do I tell it to only get just what I want and not the remainder of the file?

My code looks like this

```
pattern = @"Date:\s(?'date'\w.*)\s"
rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
matches = rgx.Matches(fileContents);
```

The fileContents looks like this snippet:

```
Date: 23 Sep 2017 

1. In this Agreement, "I", "me" and "my" refers to the account holder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to use the quantifiers that better suit your needs:

- `*` Zero or more repetitions
- `+` One or more repetitions
- `{m}` Exactly m repetitions
- `{m,n}` From m to n repetitions

If you're certain that the format for the dates will be "dd MMM yyyy", your pattern should be expressed as:

```
@"Date:\s(?'date'\d{2}\s\w{3}\s\d{4})"
```

Or you could use:

```
@"Date:\s(?'date'\d+\s\w+\s\d+)"
```

Which is less strict but makes sure that the 3 parts meant to be captured in the matching group are present.

Because of its greedy nature, you must be extra careful when using `*`, or you'll find your regex is matching much more than you intended.

Answer (score 1):

With `.*`, you are match anything in any length, so it matched the whole file.

So, your regex should be:

```
Date:\s(?'date'\d*\s\w*)\s
```

- \d* matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed \s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
- \w* matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])